# Way to place (duplicate) objects along a path

Tags: unreal-engine4

The arches and columns in the image below were manually placed. Is there a quick way to place them along a path and if so is there a way to set the distance between them? I think Houdini has this feature.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you need is a spline mesh component. If you download the blueprint content examples from the launcher they have a fence example which should be easy to modify to do what you need.

[UE4 Blueprint Splines Documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Resources/ContentExamples/Blueprint_Splines/)

Answer (score 0):

With Splines this should be fairly simple. You would have to create a blueprint that spawns meshes along an spline at a specific distance.